# How to describe recommend baseline with pipeline

Tags: clearcase, cleartool, clearcase-ucm

I am trying to find all the components baselines associated in a composite baseline.

I am able to achieve it using following way

```
cleartool desc -fmt %[rec_bls]CXp stream:My_Integration@\My_PVOB

(I would save the receommended baselines in some variable using powershell and replace it in next command) 

cleartool describe -l baseline:"$Baseline"@\My_PVOB
```

Is it possible to combine both command so that i can describe all the recommended baselines.

In the above approach i am forced to use some script to save baselines then to use it in Cleartool command. If it can be combined in cleartool itself it will be good and handy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn4t find a way to pipe the two `describe` between the composite baseline and its member baselines.

My solution (which isn't satisfactory) is, in a bash (available on Windows through msyswwin, with a tool like [msysgit](http://code.google.com/p/msysgit/)):

```
$ ct descr -l baseline:P_Summit_HUB_12_30_2011@\\Summit_HUB_pvob |grep "b)"|awk '{print "cleartool descr -fmt \"%[component]Xp %n\\n\" baseline:" $1 " >> afile"}'
```

I use whatever `fmt` I need (here just the name of the component associated with the member baseline and its name)

Then I execute each output line in order to get the final result in '`afile`'.

Your PowerShell script approach is certainly better.

---

Actually, the [OP Samselvaprabu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/399145/samselvaprabu) confirms following said PowerShell approach:

```
$Baselinefile="C:\Baseline.txt" 
$project="MyComponents@\My_PVOB" 
$pvob="@\My_PVOB" 

# Find the list of Recommended baseline for the project 
$Baselines=(cleartool lsproject -fmt "%[rec_bls]p" $project).split() 

#Foreach baseline get the baseline and Component Name 
foreach ($Bline in $Baselines) { 
  cleartool describe -l baseline:"$Bline"$pvob | Select-string -pattern "@\\My_PVOB)"| Out-File $BaselineFile -append 
}
```

Comment: Ok. I am using following powershell to tackle the issue. "$Baselinefile="C:\Baseline.txt"
$project="MyComponents@\My_PVOB"
$pvob="@\My_PVOB"

# Find the list of Recommended baseline for the project
$Baselines=(cleartool lsproject -fmt "%[rec_bls]p" $project).split()

#Foreach baseline get the baseline and Component Name
foreach ($Bline in $Baselines) {

cleartool describe -l baseline:"$Bline"$pvob | Select-string -pattern "@\\My_PVOB\)"| Out-File  $BaselineFile -append 

} " Hope it may help others in future

Comment: @Samselvaprabu: Interesting feedback, thank you. I have included your script in my answer for more visibility.

Comment: @VonC :  In your command pipe ... |grep "b)"|...   is this correct?  What is the significance?

Comment: @jayan I suspect (3 years later) that I was after lines which contained "b)", probably because it hab "vob)" in it ( I cannot test it right now)