# How can i list the recommended base line in ClearCase

Tags: shell, clearcase, cleartool, baseline

[image]

I'm currently writing a script that has to check the recommended baseline of the Integration stream, so the only parameters that I know is the stream name, I'm wondering if there is a way to do that using cleartool on linux (bash script).

Here is my Vob:

And this is the Stream:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [fmt_ccase option](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/fmt_ccase.htm) `%[rec_bls]CXp`:

On Windows:

```
cleartool descr -fmt "%[rec_bls]CXp" stream:streamName@\aPVob
```

On Unix:

```
cleartool descr -fmt "%[rec_bls]CXp" stream:streamName@/vobs/aPVob
```

You can see that command used in "[How to describe recommend baseline with pipeline](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8757144/6309)".

---

> I have a few components in this stream, how should I mention which one I want?

Recommended baselines are associated to an UCM project or UCM stream, and include one or several components.
So you need to list those baselines first, then, for each one, check if your component(s) is included.

For each baseline found, you can list its component, as shown in "[how to find `root[folder]` for each component using `cleartool`?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8769988/6309)"

```
cleartool lsbl -fmt "%[component]p" baseline:baselineName@\aPVob
```

(as usual, replace '`streamName`', '`baselineName`' or '`aPVob`' with the appropriate names in your case)

Comment: No i got this error: 
Error: No match for wildcard: "descr -fmt"%[rec_bls]CXp" stream:RavenPlat1.5.5.0_Int@/vobs/tlv_pvob"

Comment: What command did you type? Why is there no space between your descr and your double quote?

Comment: i've edited the command and now i'm getting this error:
Error: Unable to determine VOB for pathname "/vobs/tlv_pvob"

Comment: Remember, always type your cleartool command in a regular shell (not in a cleartool shell): so type `cleartool descr ...`, not '`descr ...`'

Comment: Right-click on your pvob (as show on your screenshot), and select properties: you will see its path.

Comment: I have 2 options: 
1) Properties of Folder
2) Properties of Project VOB
Which one should i choose?

Comment: option 2, properties of the pvob

Comment: Should i use the Global path or the Host path or the VOB tag?

Comment: You should use the vob tags: it should be `/vobs/yourPVob`. If it is `\yourPVob`, that would mean you are on Windows, which you said in your question you were not.

Comment: So now i'm testing it on windows, and my vob tag is: \tlv_pvob 
Should i change the command if i'm on Windows now ?

Comment: @user3502786 no, you said explitely in your question that you were on linux. But, if you actually are on Windows, then I will edit my answer.

Comment: @user3502786 you said: "using cleartool on linux (bash script).": where do you see Windows in there?

Comment: I'll use this command on linux, but now before i'm moving this to production i want to test it on Windows

Comment: As i can see it's adding ty my baseline "@/vobs/tlv_pvob" how can i print it without this ?\

Comment: @user3502786 not easy, so it is best to process the string in a separate shell command (like `awk`, or `sed`) to remove the `@/...` part

Comment: Do you have any suggestions for this ? If yes pls write me some example.
Thanks

Comment: @user3502786 it would be best as a separate section, with a clear example of the output you have, and the output you want.

Comment: this is my output :
baseline:RAVENPLAT1.5.5.0_1.5.5.0-318_CHASSIS_PKG_193_15-AUG-2014_0350@/vobs/tlv_pvob
I want untill the '@' sign

Comment: @user3502786 I mean in a separate question, with an example of the script which produces that output, and also the script language that you are using.

Comment: @user3502786 I see you have already a lot of good suggestions in http://stackoverflow.com/q/25529699/6309 :)