# printing a substring in a bash script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

I have a string :

```
baseline=RAVENPLAT1.5.5.0_1.5.5.0-318_CHASSIS_PKG_193_15-AUG-2014_0350@/vobs/tlv_pvob
```

I'm trying to get into a variable the subtring untill the '@' sign is it possible?

Comment: is `baseline` a variable?

Comment: Yes which holds this string...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using BASH regex:

```
baseline=RAVENPLAT1.5.5.0_1.5.5.0-318_CHASSIS_PKG_193_15-AUG-2014_0350@/vobs/tlv_pvob

[[ "$baseline" =~ ^([^@]+) ]] && myvar="${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"

echo "$myvar"
RAVENPLAT1.5.5.0_1.5.5.0-318_CHASSIS_PKG_193_15-AUG-2014_0350
```

OR else using BASH string manipulations:

```
myvar="${baseline%%@*}"
```

Answer (score 4):

Use Parameter Expansion:

```
$ baseline=RAVENPLAT1.5.5.0_1.5.5.0-318_CHASSIS_PKG_193_15-AUG-2014_0350@/vobs/tlv_pvob
$ echo "${baseline%%@*}"
RAVENPLAT1.5.5.0_1.5.5.0-318_CHASSIS_PKG_193_15-AUG-2014_0350
```

Comment: @JohnB `b=foo@bar@baz; echo "(${b%@*})" -> (foo@bar); echo "(${b%%@*})" -> foo`. So, no, you need `%%` here. Assuming you want up to the first `@` and not up to the last `@` that is.

Comment: +1 You can also just do it with `${baseline%@*}` since `*` matches everything after `@`.

Comment: @EtanReisner Yup, if there are multiple `@` in the string, and you want everything removed after the first `@`, you'd need `%%`.

Comment: lets say that my input is : RavenPlat1.5.4.1 
How can i get just the numbers?

Comment: @user3502786 If the input is *only* `RavenPlat1.5.4.1` (or after the above manipulation that's what you are left with) and the string `RavenPlat` is known ahead of time and static you can use `${invar#RavenPlat}`. If it isn't known or constant then you need to do something like `pfx=${invar%%[[:digit:].]*}; echo ${invar#$pfx}`.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like

```
x = "baseline=RAVENPLAT1.5.5.0_1.5.5.0-318_CHASSIS_PKG_193_15-AUG-2014_0350@/vobs/tlv_pvob"
y = "@"
z = ${x/$y*/$y}
```

Not tested - maybe the last character from z will be removed using something similar to:

```
${z:0:-1}
```

Answer (score 1):

Hope you've only 1 @ in your string -

```
 a=abc@b.c
 echo ` echo $a | tr @ ' ' | awk '{print $1}'`
```

Comment: What does the tr means ?

Comment: tr is translate or substitute, i substituted @ with space - made it as 2 (or more) strings and applied awk to get the 1st column/string. More tr [link]http://www.computerhope.com/unix/utr.htm