# Rebase a stream on linux using cleartool

Tags: linux, clearcase, clearcase-ucm, cleartool

It's a very basic question, which command shoud i use in linux to rebase my stream, my stream name is : 
abrodov_RavenApp1.5.5.0_Plat_Mig_1 , it's located in : //home/RND/abrodov/views.

Answer (score 1):

It should be [`cleartool rebase`](https://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m0/topic/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_rebase.htm):

```
cd /path/to/myUCMview
cleartool rebase -bas yourBaseline@/vobs/yourPVob
```

Note: don't mix a view name and a stream name. Your view must be an UCM view associated to the stream.

You can check which stream is associated with your view with:

```
cd /path/to/myUCMview
cleartool lsstream -cview
```

Comment: how can i check what is my current baseline ?

Comment: Rebasing is about changing the baseline by one of your choice (coming from the parent stream). If you don't specify a baseline, it will take the ones of the parent which have been recommended. You can see the recommended baselines of a stream graphically (right-click on the stream, "recommended baselines"). Or with cleartool, as I explained it in your previous question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25427175/6309

Comment: so this is the command that i should type: 
rebase -bas abrodov_RavenApp1.5.5.0_Plat_Mig_1@/vobs/myPVob

Comment: Yes, if abrodov_RavenApp1.5.5.0_Plat_Mig_1@/vobs/myPVob is the name of a baseline.

Comment: If i'm using a dunamic view should i rebase ?

Comment: @user3502786 rebase is not linked to snapshot or dynamic view, but it is easier to rebase using a dynamic view (not load to perform)

Comment: I tried to rebase and i got this error:
cleartool: Error: Can't rebase to baseline "GSRM_4.02_31-AUG-14_1715"
of component "GSRM" because it was created in this stream.
cleartool: Error: Unable to rebase stream "GSRM_4.02_Integ".

Comment: @user3502786 when you are not in an integration stream, you only rebase a baseline created in the parent stream.