# How do I debug a java.lang.illegalStateException that occurs when rebasing a ClearCase view?

Tags: eclipse, clearcase, rebase

## Background

I have been trying for the last week to rebase a clearcase view for my project, but every time I try I get a weird null exception depicted in the two windows below:
[image]
I do not know why this is occurring and need help determining how to even begin fixing this issue.

So far here is what I have tried:

1. Restarting the client
2. Restarting my computer
3. Refreshing the view and updating.
4. Updating my eclipse environment.

I have also seen a fix on the [IBM website](https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/apar/PI64193) for a similar issue, but my version of Clearteam explorer is well beyond the version it prescribes for a fix:

> When you are trying to login with the IBM Rational ClearTeam
> Explorer (CTE) version 8.0.1.11 and later with the Eclipse
> plugin, you may receive the following error: CRMAP7009: Command
> "Login" failed: Error: "java.lang.IllegalStateException: null"

> This behavior does not occur with CTE 8.0.1.10 with the Eclipse
> plugin or with the standalone CTE 8.0.1.11 client.
> It only occurs using the Sun JRE 6, not when using the IBM JRE
> 6.

My clearteam explorer version is 9.0.2:
[image]

## Question

What are other possible actions I can take to fix the null pointer issue mentioned above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, you're going to hate this, but the only thing I can do is ask questions and point you to IBM/HCL support.

1. Is this a web-based view? A snapshot view? A Dynamic view?
2. Does a new view work?
3. Are there any errors in the CTE workspace log? (%USERPROFILE%.Rational\CTE8\workspace.log)
4. Is this the CTE plugin installed into Eclipse? Or the CTE "full" client? And does it matter?
5. Have you tried this using the command line interface (cleartool/rcleartool as appropriate)
6. Does running in debug mode tell us anything additional? (See https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/how-enable-trace-ccrc-client-and-server) Note that on windows, CTE/eclipse will spawn a separate console window to print some eclipse diagnostic output that may or may not be important. You'll want to capture that before exiting the session.
7. If this is a web-based view, has anyone checked the WAN server logs?

CRMAP7009 is a "catch all" message for CTE, but since that is an exception message, it should be expanded upon SOMEWHERE. Half the battle is finding the rest of the message.

Comment: I have solved the issue.  It pertained to question 4.  Because it wasn't a full client, it messed up the system somehow.  Thank you Brian.

Answer (score 0):

In those case, I always try and fall back to command line, using in your case [`cleartool rebase`](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/rational-clearcase/9.0.2?topic=ucm-rebase).
See "[Rebase a stream on linux using cleartool](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25547662/6309)" (the same idea applies on Windows), and "[How to rebase in ClearCase on latest baselines?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63036258/6309)".

That way, I can see if the issue is with ClearCase itself or with the Eclipse ClearCase plugin.